# how to show random data from the data base file .i am getting confusion as i am getting errors

Tags: java, android

i am new to android programming.i looking to make a question and answer application.in this application i fetch the data from the data base file as follows

```
public String makeatext(String My_database_table, int i) {
    SQLiteDatabase myDB = getDatabase();
    String results = new String();
     Cursor cur = null;
    try {
        String firstColumn = "questions";
                 cur = myDB.query(true, My_database_table,
                new String[] { firstColumn }, null, null, null, null, null,
                null);

        int iquestion = cur.getColumnIndex(firstColumn);
        if (cur.moveToPosition(i)) {
            results = results + cur.getString(iquestion) + "\n";

        }
        return results;

    }
    catch (Exception e) {e.printStackTrace();
        Log.e("ERROR", "ERROR in Make test file :" + e.toString());
        e.printStackTrace();
        // TODO: handle exception
    }finally{
        cur.close();    
    }
    return results;
}
```

and in my main activity class i am initializing random value as

```
 Random questions;
questions  = new Random();
int Rnumber;Rnumber=0;
Rnumber=questions.nextInt(3);
```

and after setting the random value i am calling the function as

`String shoow = myDb.makeatext(levels, Rnumber);`
now i am getting a question but .what i want is as every time user opens application i want to show random questions.how to do this any suggestions will be very good to me
thanks,
maddy

Answer (score 0, accepted):

move line

```
questions  = new Random();
```

to onCreate()

and

```
Rnumber=questions.nextInt(3); //Rnumber can get 0, 1, 2 values
```

to onResume

Do You have only 3 questions????

Comment: well the first line is in onCreate() method itself. i moved to onResume() and now it is working Vovs.Thank u for this.really i appreciated man